# Sound output not available by default on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sound, thinkpad

I am using Lenovo ThinkPad E480 [plugged to a dock](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/universal-cable-docks-usb/ThinkPad-USB-3-0-Pro-Dock/p/40A70045US), and by default, I always turn my computer on with both plugged in. No issues within this configuration.

But when I turn my computer on without dock plugged in, I do only see "Dummy output" as my Sound Output option. As a result, no sound available.

After tweaking a while, I found two different options to solve this:

1) Either plug my dock to PC, and then PC Speaker output becomes available;

2) Or run this command: `$pulseaudio && sudo alsa force-reload`

What is the reason for such? I'm trying to understand if it was some kernel update that caused it, or there's some concurrency issue going on, or any other factor I haven't considered so far...

Thanks in advance.